# Tiny MCE WYSIWYG Problem with v-model | Only Google Chrome

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg

I am trying to integrate Tiny MCE editor with Vue js, I installed this package with npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tinymce-editor

In the reseuces / js / app.js source file, I imported the component

```js
import tinymce from 'vue-tinymce-editor'
Vue.component('tinymce', tinymce);
```

The component was created simply like this

```html
<tinymce id="1"
         :other_options="tinyOptions"
         v-model="menu"></tinymce>
```

'menu' is the variable in vue data js. 
Vue does not report errors in the Chome console, in fact the component renders correctly. The problem is that it works with the Safari browser and not with others such as Google Chrome. A bug in all respects. Has anyone faced this problem before?
I attach the screenshots of the two views on Safari and Chrome.
[Chrome bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SBFw.png)[Safari works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBPad.png)

Comment: I tried your code. If the value of "other_options" is correctly defined, it works fine works under Firefox and Chrome

Comment: What do you mean by properly defined? You can also remove the options as they are optional. I'm running the project with Laravel mix, in a Laravel project. I am not using Vue CLI. @Joulss

Comment: By "correctly defined" I mean "defined". However the test I made was in a vue-cli project, I'm not familiar with Laravel so I'm afraid I can't help you more...